# Cron и запуск jar с параметрами

Tags: ubuntu

Как запустить jar с параметрами через cron,

```
Java -jar bla.jar -bla bla?
```

Если поставить адрес в кавычки, то он ругается, что нет такого каталога java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в кавычках

Comment: тогда замени java на полный путь (можно узнать введя which java)